# Как вывести все данные?

Tags: c++, c++11

Не могу отсортировать продавцов по фамилии, а также не получается вывести всех продавцов (выводятся только 2). На Java сделала с помощью Collections, а вот по С++ не знаю. Заранее спасибо.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Vanzator
{
private:

    std::string m_id;
    std::string m_FirstName;
    std::string m_LastName;
    int m_age;
    std::string m_expereenta;

public:

    Vanzator(std::string id, std::string FirstName, std::string LastName, int age, std::string expereenta)
    {
        m_id = id;
        m_FirstName = FirstName;
        m_LastName = LastName;
        m_age = age;
        m_expereenta = expereenta;
    }

    //Inceputul blocului cu functii get...
    std::string getId()
    {
        std::cout << m_id << std::endl;;
        return m_id;
    }

    std::string getFirstName()
    {
        std::cout << m_FirstName << std::endl;;
        return m_FirstName;
    }

    std::string getLastName()
    {
        std::cout << m_LastName << std::endl;;
        return m_LastName;
    }

    int getAge()
    {
        std::cout << m_age << std::endl;;
        return m_age;
    }

    std::string getExpereenta()
    {
        std::cout << m_expereenta << std::endl;;
        return m_expereenta;
    }
    //Sfarsitul blocului cu functii get...


    //Inceputul blocului cu functii set...
    void setId(std::string id)
    {
        m_id  = id;
    }

    void setFirstName(std::string firstName)
    {
        m_FirstName = firstName;
    }

    void setLastName(std::string lastName)
    {
        m_LastName = lastName;
    }

    void setAge(int age)
    {
        m_age = age;
    }

    void setExpereenta(std::string expereenta)
    {
        m_expereenta = expereenta;
    }
    //Sfarsitul blocului cu functii set...

    std::string toString()
    {
        std::cout << "\nVanzator {" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tid = " << m_id << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tFirstName = " << m_FirstName << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tLastName = " << m_LastName << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tage = " << m_age << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tExpereenta = " << m_expereenta << std::endl;
        std::cout << "}" << std::endl;

    }


};


kkk#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Vanzator
{
private:

    std::string m_id;
    std::string m_FirstName;
    std::string m_LastName;
    int m_age;
    std::string m_expereenta;

public:

    Vanzator(std::string id, std::string FirstName, std::string LastName, int age, std::string expereenta)
    {
        m_id = id;
        m_FirstName = FirstName;
        m_LastName = LastName;
        m_age = age;
        m_expereenta = expereenta;
    }

    //Inceputul blocului cu functii get...
    std::string getId()
    {
        std::cout << m_id << std::endl;;
        return m_id;
    }

    std::string getFirstName()
    {
        std::cout << m_FirstName << std::endl;;
        return m_FirstName;
    }

    std::string getLastName()
    {
        std::cout << m_LastName << std::endl;;
        return m_LastName;
    }

    int getAge()
    {
        std::cout << m_age << std::endl;;
        return m_age;
    }

    std::string getExpereenta()
    {
        std::cout << m_expereenta << std::endl;;
        return m_expereenta;
    }
    //Sfarsitul blocului cu functii get...


    //Inceputul blocului cu functii set...
    void setId(std::string id)
    {
        m_id  = id;
    }

    void setFirstName(std::string firstName)
    {
        m_FirstName = firstName;
    }

    void setLastName(std::string lastName)
    {
        m_LastName = lastName;
    }

    void setAge(int age)
    {
        m_age = age;
    }

    void setExpereenta(std::string expereenta)
    {
        m_expereenta = expereenta;
    }
    //Sfarsitul blocului cu functii set...

    std::string toString()
    {
        std::cout << "\nVanzator {" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tid = " << m_id << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tFirstName = " << m_FirstName << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tLastName = " << m_LastName << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tage = " << m_age << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tExpereenta = " << m_expereenta << std::endl;
        std::cout << "}" << std::endl;

    }


};


main()
{
    
Vanzator Vanzator1("0001884125", "Maxim", "Bortinlov", 25, "2 ani");
    
Vanzator Vanzator2("0001884572", "Anastasia", "Sumanova", 30, "5 ani");
   
 Vanzator Vanzator3("0001884424", "Grigorii", "Edganov", 24, "1 an");
 
   Vanzator Vanzator4("0001884354", "Leonid", "Samarov", 21, "3 luni");

    Vanzator1.toString(); //Afiseaza datele vanzatorului 1


    Vanzator2.setExpereenta("1.5 ani");

    Vanzator2.toString(); 
    Vanzator3.toString();
    Vanzator4.toString();

}
```

Comment: Обычно никто не хочет продираться через огромные исходники... :( Кстати, если уж объявляете функцию возвращающей что-то (строку), так возвращайте ее! Еще - у вас тут два кода; какой рассматривать? И оба, кстати, не компилируются - так что как у вас программа ухитряется что-то делать вообще - непонятно... Кстати, стоило изменить `main()` на `int main()`, а `std::string toString()` на `void toString()`, как (второй) исходник скомпилировался и вывел все 4 набора данных...

Comment: Только то обстоятельство, что любой может  менять имя  продавца, уже  делает весь код  не осмысленным

Comment: Знаю ,что мой код без смысла , просто я тренируюсь

Comment: кстати мой код- компилируется

Comment: @Catea приведите [mre]. Сейчас у вас 2 файла как будто

Comment: @Catea Я попробовал скомпилировать. Компилятор Visual C++ жалуется на отсутствие int у main и на отсутствие return в toString(). Вы чем компилируете?

Answer (score 0):

Обычно никто не хочет продираться через огромные исходники... :( Кстати, если уж объявляете функцию возвращающей что-то (строку), так возвращайте ее! Еще - у вас тут два кода; какой рассматривать? И оба, кстати, не компилируются - так что как у вас программа ухитряется что-то делать вообще - непонятно... Кстати, стоило изменить `main()` на `int main()`, а `std::string toString()` на `void toString()`, как (второй) исходник скомпилировался и вывел все 4 набора данных...